# linear independence, convex hull, and cone

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-hulls, convex-cone

I am trying to show that for any set, $A\neq \{ 0\}$ and any $x\in co(cone A) \subset \mathbb{R^n}$, there exists linearly independent set $A' \subset A$ such that $x\in co (cone A')$.

Here, co(A) means convex hull of set A, and cone(A) means the cone generated by a set A.

I think some how I have to use

co(cone A) = cone(co A)=$\{ \sum ^{k} _{i=1} \lambda_i x^{(i)} | k\in \mathbb{N}, \lambda_i \geq0, x^{(i)}\in A\}$, where $x^{(i)}$ is a vector in $A$

But, I am not sure why and where we need linear independence here and how to sue the linear independency. Please give me some advice.

Comment: According to the Caratheodory's Theorem, this linear independence is really not necessary.

Comment: Assume $x=\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i x^{(i)}$ with dependent $x^{(i)}$'s, wlog. $x^{(k)}$ is a linear combination of the rest. Now try to conclude that we can drop some $x^{(i)}$ and still get $x$ as the positive combination of the rest..